# Date in composite primary key column is not working for oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, primary-key

Date data type in primary key is not working for oracle. Please help me to understand.

```
 CREATE TABLE USER_TABLE1 (
          SSN                       VARCHAR2(10 CHAR)           NOT NULL,
          DOB                       DATE                        NOT NULL,
          USER_NAME                 VARCHAR2(50)                NOT NULL,
          constraint USER_TABLE1_PK primary key(SSN,DOB)
        )
        
        insert into USER_TABLE1 values('SSN1',sysdate,'User1');
        
        select * from USER_TABLE1;
```

**Results:**

```
SSN DOB USER_NAME
SSN1    15-JUL-22   User1
SSN1    15-JUL-22   User1
```

Update:
[image]

Comment: DATE in Oracle contains also time information. I guess your records have different time in the column DOB

Comment: Any reference for more details would be really helpful.

Comment: Any reference is always a [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/sqlrf/Data-Types.html#GUID-7B72E154-677A-4342-A1EA-C74C1EA928E6): "This data type contains the **datetime** fields YEAR, MONTH, DAY, **HOUR, MINUTE, and SECOND**. It does not have fractional seconds or a time zone."

Answer (score 1):

In Oracle, a `DATE` data type is a binary data type consisting of 7 bytes representing: century, year-of-century, month, day, hour, minute and second. It **ALWAYS** has those components and is not stored in any particular (human-readable) format.

What you are seeing is the client application choosing to display the `DATE` in a format that is comprehensible to you, the user, and the implicit conversion it has used to convert the unformatted binary to a formatted string is only displaying the day-month-year components and the time components are not displayed.

If you do:

```sql
select ssn,
       TO_DATE(dob, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') AS dob,
       user_name
from   USER_TABLE1;
```

Then you will see the time component and see that the values in the primary key columns are not identical.

---

What you probably want is to require the time component of the `DATE` to always be midnight with a `CHECK` constraint:

```sql
CREATE TABLE USER_TABLE1 (
  SSN       VARCHAR2(10 CHAR) NOT NULL,
  DOB       DATE              NOT NULL,
  USER_NAME VARCHAR2(50)      NOT NULL,
  constraint user_table1__dob__chk CHECK (dob = TRUNC(dob)),
  constraint USER_TABLE1_PK primary key(SSN,DOB)
);
```

Then you cannot have `DOB` with the same day and different time components.

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=8ac4b185ada914c15a3baa6cab6529f5)*